# Dual lookup collection?

Tags: c#, collections

I have a heap of byte/string values.

I want a function/collection to look up one based on the other.  ie:  provide a byte and get the corresponding string back.  Provide a string, get the corresponding byte back.

How can I do this?

Comment: 2 Dictionarys, or just a List if its not too big. O(n)

Comment: this is really useful information to answer larger questions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple class to hold the value pair (or even a Tuple would work fine):

```
public class Item
{
    public string StrVal { get; set; }
    public byte ByteVal { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could store them in a `List<Item>` and access them like:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item {StrVal = "first", ByteVal = 1},
    new Item {StrVal = "second", ByteVal = 2},
    new Item {StrVal = "third", ByteVal = 3},
};

// Provide a byte, get the corresponding string back:
byte byteToFind = 2;
string resultStr = items.Where(i => i.ByteVal == byteToFind )
    .Select(i => i.StrVal).FirstOrDefault();

// Provide a string, get the corresponding byte back:
byte resultByte = items.Where(i => i.StrVal == resultStr)
    .Select(i => i.ByteVal).FirstOrDefault();
```